# How do I auto-login as root into the TTY upon boot?

Tags: tty, auto-login

I am working on creating a real time kernel with RT-PREEMPT patch.
I have created this kernel without graphic desktop. It comes up in the terminal mode with login prompt.
The requirement is, it should boot and directly go to the shell prompt with root permission, without asking for login.
How can this be done? Can you help me?

Answer (score 16):

source: http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/04/30/autologin-linux-console-mode.

I have gotten it to work, but it is slightly different on Ubuntu.

1. First install `mingetty`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mingetty
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/init/tty1.conf`:

   Change:

   ```
   exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
   ```

   To:

   ```
   exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin root --noclear tty1
   ```
3. Reboot and test.

This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04, if this works for you and you need more tty's to autologin start changing tty2.conf - tty6.conf and you should be good to go.

Comment: Testing it in a VM as we speak.

Comment: You'll want the `exec `.

Comment: D'oooh. You are absolutely right. I will edit :P

Comment: working for ubuntu-server 14.04 also.

Comment: what is function of "--noclear"?

Comment: `/sbin/getty` seems to supporting `--auto-login` argument as of in Ubuntu 14.04.02 now

Comment: I've made these changes on Ubuntu 15.10 and cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

In the modern world of systemd, here are the steps I took to get this working:

1. `apt install mingetty`
2. `mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d`
3. Now run the following script:

   ```
    cat > /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf <<- "_EOF_"
    [Service]
    ExecStart=
    ExecStart=-/sbin/mingetty --autologin root --noclear tty1
    _EOF_
   ```
4. `systemctl enable getty@tty1.service`

The above seems to be the cleanest option for systems that use Systemd that I could find.  As an added bonus, if something breaks in the future, you can just run something like the following from a recovery live ISO (after mounting the root partition of course), to restore default behavior:

```
rm /mnt/root/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any additional software

```
sudo vim /etc/inittab
```

comment out

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1
```

and replace it with

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

so you are left with this

```
#1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Comment: How does this differ against "1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --noclear --autologin root 38400 tty1" ?