# How to enable autologin on Ubuntu Server 14.10?

Tags: auto-login

I'm looking for how to set auto-login on Ubuntu Server 14.10 **from console**.

All information I find out there is for 14.04, and configuration files seem to have changed a lot.

Comment: I think any guide from the Upstart days would work in 14.10, for example, this one for 12.04: http://askubuntu.com/a/168713/158442

Comment: The one post I didn't see. That worked. Thanks!