# Use tty without login every time

Tags: command-line, login, tty

In the Ubuntu-based systems, from the desktop environment, it is possible to open several tabs from the terminal emulator without making a login every time: the user is already logged in for every tab (usually each tab corresponds to a `/dev/pts/x` device).

By pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 ... F6 it is possible to access a `tty` which is a fully-textual and full-screen terminal. But in contrast with the graphic terminal emulator tabs, a new login is required every time and for each new `tty`.

Is there a way to avoid this? I would like to be already logged in when I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 ... F6, when I access those text-terminals from the graphic environment (where I logged in!).

Comment: please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168706/how-do-i-auto-login-as-root-into-the-tty-upon-boot)

Comment: The problem is that the X session you're logged into runs on top of a virtual terminal as well (to be precise on `tty7`), so technically the login is "valid" only for `tty7`. One way (which has very obvious security issues) would be to setup the other `tty`s to auto-login as a specific user and set the `tty` themselves so that they won't ask for a password to let an user log in, which can be done. However would it be enough just set the `tty`s to auto-login as a specific user? That would be more safe, and you'd have to type only the password.

Comment: @Ravan thank you, it is slightly different from what I need, but useful as well.

Comment: @kos thank you for your explanation. I would choose the second solution. For my security purposes, it would certainly be enough to set one or more `tty` auto-login as a user (so that I just should type a password); how is it possible?

Comment: ok @BowPark ..but your problem solved or not?

Comment: Not sure if this will work on Ubuntu, I can't test it right now as I'm not on Ubuntu, see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14152508/4316166

Comment: @kos it is very similar to (but more general than) Serg's answer. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Ravan No, it isn't. Thanks to Serg's answer I could make an automatic login, but there is still a security issue. If you want, check out my comment to that answer.

Comment: I'm not even sure why I posted that link, the idea was that since you didn't specify a Ubuntu version perhaps a method for systemd would have been useful... But that's still for init, so I need a pair of glasses.

Comment: This is too danger. Terminals are not same with terminal emulators. If you do this thing, anyone can access all your data in your COMPUTER...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu by default uses `agetty` to manange TTYs. The man page for that defines `-a, --autologin username` options for logging in a specified username automatically. Thus one can do the following:

1. Open with root permissions `/etc/init/tty1.conf` file in your favorite text editor. I'm doing `sudo vim /etc/init/tty1.conf` but you can use `pkexec gedit /etc/init/tty1.conf`
2. Alter the default line `exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2` to `exec /sbin/getty --autologin myUserName -8 38400 tty2`.
3. Save and exit. Repeat for other tty files as necessary

Note that for single-user system this is appropriate, but not recommended when you have multiple users ( for obvious privacy reasons )

Comment: Thank you. It works. Rightly, you suggest to use it just in a single-user system. But is there a way to run this automatic login only after a successful GUI login? That is: I login in the GUI with user `myuser`, then I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to open `/dev/tty1` and `myuser` is automatically logged in tty1. If I open tty1 before any login in the system with `myuser`, tty1 will request a login as in the default configuration. Is there a way to achieve this? If you think it is too long to discuss here, I could open another question.

Comment: @BowPark there may be a way, but I am not entirely positive - I've an untested idea, so once I have it tested, I will let you know

Answer (score 1):

See `man screen`, it says, in part:

```
DESCRIPTION
       Screen  is  a  full-screen  window  manager that multiplexes a physical
       terminal between  several  processes  (typically  interactive  shells).
       Each  virtual  terminal  provides the functions of a DEC VT100 terminal
       and, in addition, several control functions from the ISO 6429 (ECMA 48,
       ANSI X3.64) and ISO 2022 standards (e.g. insert/delete line and support
       for multiple character sets).  There is a scrollback history buffer for
       each virtual terminal and a copy-and-paste mechanism that allows moving
       text regions between windows.
```

I use it on <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd> screens all the time